# jQuery custom theme?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 jQuery themes. A custom theme and a theme with the scope sidebar. But now I need to mix both themes in the sidebar?

For example:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div id="accordionwidget">
        <div id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The accordion widget and the datepicker are both using the theme with the scope sidebar. But I like to use the custom-theme for the datepicker.

Do I need to copy the custom theme and scope it datepicker? If I do, I double the CSS files. Or can I add a class to the datepicker to override the scope sidebar?

Comment: You have manually write or modify css code as per requirement. Because  class assign in datepicker from jquery file

Answer (score 1):

This is not good practice, but in some times it could be ok to use the `!important` in CSS. Using `!important` will override any preexisting styles.

Example:

HTML:

```
<p class="blue">

</p>
```

CSS:

```
p.blue{
    color: yellow; /* will get overridden */
}

.blue{
   color: blue !important;
}
```

You can read up more on [using !important here](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: In fairness, even without the !important the second css rule would override the first

Comment: that's better! :) Yes a little nitpickedness but could be confusing for OP.